# Issue with big file when use mahout

Tags: java, mahout, mahout-recommender

I have problem when I try to launch a big file when use User-Based Recommender. I follow the "tutorial" step by step and launch the example and don't have any problem, but when I put my file (have 100k line) have the follow problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at com.google.common.base.AbstractIterator.next(AbstractIterator.java:75)
at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel.processLine(FileDataModel.java:407)
at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel.processFile(FileDataModel.java:363)
at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel.buildModel(FileDataModel.java:259)
at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel.reload(FileDataModel.java:231)
at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel.<init>(FileDataModel.java:221)
at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel.<init>(FileDataModel.java:169)
at org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.file.FileDataModel.<init>(FileDataModel.java:149)
at com.predictionmarketing.RecommenderApp.App.main(App.java:21)
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

May be file you are giving is having empty rows.

Please check the last row if it is empty.Rry to place mouse pointer there at end of file and if mouse comes in empty row than delete the row.